# biblatex: No pagebreak in bibliography entry

Tags: biblatex, page-breaking

Is it possible to tell `biblatex` to never split a bibliography entry across two pages?
Ideally this should work for both `\cite` and `\fullcite`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`biblatex` executes `\bibsetup` at the start of the bibliography; its usual definition is

```
\interlinepenalty=5000\relax
\widowpenalty=10000\relax
\clubpenalty=10000\relax
\raggedbottom
\frenchspacing
\biburlsetup
```

So you can do

```
\patchcmd{\bibsetup}{\interlinepenalty=5000}{\interlinepenalty=10000}{}{}
```

and this will inhibit page breaks inside paragraphs.

The utility `\patchcmd` requires, in general, to load the `etoolbox` package, but `biblatex` already loads it.

Comment: That's more what I was looking for, thanks. Do I need to load a package for this to to work?

Comment: Do these affect both the "bibliography" and in text citations? I think the question is about in text citations.

Comment: @Daniel: it's about both :-), but primarily the "bibliography", I don't using that many in-text citaitons, so there I can manually put some \pagebreaks

Comment: @egreg: I added a clarification on the required `etoolbox` package. Please approve my edit :)

Comment: @Matthias The clarification was good and partly I included it, but `biblatex` already loads `etoolbox`.

Comment: This does not seem to be working for me when bibliography entries consist of 4 or more lines and the split occurs after line 2. Actually setting it myself (`\interlinepenalty=10000`) right before calling `\bibliography` did work.

Comment: @Joost `\interlinepenalty5000` just highly discourages page breaking, but it doesn't inhibit it.

Comment: This solution seems to have stopped working with the current biblatex version. I do get line breaks in some `fullcite` blocks now. Any ideas?

Comment: I had the same issue as @Joost and his solution also worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

More a kludge than a true automagic solution:

As BibTeX is a seperate executable that writes the LaTeX code that typesets the bibliography in a .bbl file, which then again is read into LaTeX in the next run, you can simply manually insert a `\pagebreak` between two `\bibitems` in the .bbl file to make sure the second one is moved completely to the next page.

As BibTeX is not aware of the layout of the page the size of the fonts etc. it cannot decide where to insert such a `\pagebreak` itself. It might be possible to modify `\bibitem` to check whether it fits on the current page but that is most likely not a trivial thing to do.

Of course you loose the manually inserted `\pagebreaks` whenever you have to rerun BibTeX, so it is best to do this at the very end before publishing, when there are no more changes to the bibliography, to avoid doing this over and over again.

Comment: But then I would need to edit the bbl file everytime I change/add things to my bibliography?

Comment: @Matthias True. As I wrote, it is a kludge. If you do it at the very end before publishing/printing you only have to do it once.

Comment: I see. Well, this not really practical for me. But thanks anyway!