# Using biblatex, multicols, defbibenvironment, how to keep list items together

Tags: biblatex, minipage, multicolumn

Using **Biblatex**, I can produce a double-columned bibliography with the following definition:

```
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}{%
        \begin{multicols}{2}%
        \enumerate[noitemsep,nolistsep]{}{}%
}{%
        \endenumerate%
        \end{multicols}%
}{\item}%
```

However, I would like to prevent an individual item from breaking between columns or between pages (an individual item to be kept together).

Having previously used BibTeX, I was able to achieve this using mini-pages, enclosing each record via the style file, I am unsure how to apply the same approach in this situation.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Does this help http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43275/2388?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `begentry` and `finentry` to wrap a bibliographic entry in a mini page, namely

```
\renewbibmacro{begentry}{\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}}
\renewbibmacro{finentry}{\finentry\end{minipage}}
```

Comment: More flexible would be `1\linewidth` when columns are already defined.