# Prevent page and column breaks mid bibliography entries in Biblatex/biber

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, page-breaking, biber, columnbreak

Using `biblatex` and `biber` is there any way to prevent a page/column break from occurring mid item? The image below shows bibliography items being split both at the end of a column and at the end of the page. I have found that setting `block=npar` solves the issue, but also reformats the bibliography by inserting line breaks in the individual entries.

**How can I protect bibliography entries from page and column breaks within the bibliography?**

As you can see entries are split across columns and pages both, neither of which looks particularly good. Moreover, as the image illustrates some issues are also visible after a page break: LaTeX splits a large entry in two across both columns. I would like LaTeX to enter both entries in the same column below one another.

I have included a MWE and an image from my actual work.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents} 
 \begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
  @article{DoeA,
  title={The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog},
  author={Doe, John and Bar, Foo and Bob, Joe and Kid, Billy The and Lucky, Luke and Kong, King},
  journal={Journal A of supposed excellence and uncomfortably long titles to make this example work. },
  year={2001}
  }
    @article{DoeB,
  title={The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog},
  author={Doe, John and Bar, Foo and Bob, Joe and Kid, Billy The and Lucky, Luke and Kong, King},
  journal={Journal B of supposed excellence and uncomfortably long titles to make this example work. },
  year={2001}
  }
    @article{DoeC,
  title={The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog},
  author={Doe, John and Bar, Foo and Bob, Joe and Kid, Billy The and Lucky, Luke and Kong, King},
  journal={Journal C of supposed excellence and uncomfortably long titles to make this example work. },
  year={2001}
  }

  @article{Genius02,
  title={Title B},
  author={Genius, Evil and Vader, Darth},
  journal={Journal B},
  year={2002}

}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{multicol}
  \usepackage[left=2.1cm,right=1.4cm,top=23.5cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}%Etter mal fra npprj


  \usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \nocite{DoeA,DoeB,DoeC,Genius02}

\printbibliography
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Check [biblatex: No pagebreak in bibliography entry](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43260/35864) and [Using biblatex, multicols, defbibenvironment, how to keep list items together](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/130190/35864), but see also the discussion [here](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/273).

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that you need to change the values of different penaltys to `10000` (not allowed).

The easierst way to do that is to patch the relevant commands with package `etoolbox` and the command `\patchcmd{\command-to-be-patched}{search-code}{replace-code}{sucess}{failure}` (please see the comments!):

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}  % <============================ to patch penaltys
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\clubpenalty4000}{\clubpenalty10000}{}{}     % no orphans
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\widowpenalty4000}{\widowpenalty10000}{}{}   % no widows
\patchcmd{\bibsetup}{\interlinepenalty=5000}{\interlinepenalty=10000}{}{} % no break of entry
```

So with this complete MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents} 
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{DoeA,
  title={The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog},
  author={Doe, John and Bar, Foo and Bob, Joe and Kid, Billy The and Lucky, Luke and Kong, King},
  journal={Journal A of supposed excellence and uncomfortably long titles to make this example work. },
  year={2001},
}
@article{DoeB,
  title={The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog},
  author={Doe, John and Bar, Foo and Bob, Joe and Kid, Billy The and Lucky, Luke and Kong, King},
  journal={Journal B of supposed excellence and uncomfortably long titles to make this example work. },
  year={2001}
}
@article{DoeC,
  title={The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog},
  author={Doe, John and Bar, Foo and Bob, Joe and Kid, Billy The and Lucky, Luke and Kong, King},
  journal={Journal C of supposed excellence and uncomfortably long titles to make this example work. },
  year={2001},
}
@article{Genius02,
  title={Title B},
  author={Genius, Evil and Vader, Darth},
  journal={Journal B},
  year={2002},
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[left=2.1cm,right=1.4cm,top=23.5cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{showframe} % <========================= to show typing area!
\usepackage{etoolbox}  % <============================ to patch penaltys
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\clubpenalty4000}{\clubpenalty10000}{}{}     % no orphans
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\widowpenalty4000}{\widowpenalty10000}{}{}   % no widows
\patchcmd{\bibsetup}{\interlinepenalty=5000}{\interlinepenalty=10000}{}{} % no break of entry


\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\nocite{DoeA,DoeB,DoeC,Genius02}

\printbibliography
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

you get the following result (I used package `showframe` to visualise the resulting typing area):

[image: first page of shown pdf]