Latex installation or workspace configuration breaking \begin{enumerate}
Task Description: I am writing my thesis with latex in vscode. Sometimes I write using my desktop PC and other times using my laptop when I am travelling. I have setup git version control for this reason and for obvious backup reasons.
Issue Description: I tried making a list using the itemize function, which caused several issues when building the project only in my desktop. Things work fine when I am working on my laptop. In addition, I am getting warnings regarding undefined citations, even though the entries are in the .bib file and the built pdf file shows the correct citation number.
Debug message: The troubling code and accompanying error messages are shown below.


When I comment out this part of the code, I get the error message

I am attaching main.tex code to show the preamble.
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[
  dissertation
 ,final
 ,raggedbottom
%,tocbold        % uncomment to enable bold chapter titles in the ToC
                 %
                 % the style guidelines state that page numbers in the
                 % ToC should not be bold, but leave it up to the author
                 % and specific department guidelines as to how the
                 % chapter (or other section) titles should be typeset.
]{USCthesis}

% guidelines for manuscript formatting: https://graduateschool.usc.edu/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/Manuscript_Formatting_and_Documentation_Styles.pdf

%% our customizations %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% \usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % for frame option in \includegraphics
\usepackage{amssymb} % for mathematical symbols
% \usepackage{array} % for advanced table formatting
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % for input encoding
\usepackage[english]{babel} % for language support
\usepackage[backend=biber, doi=true, hyperref=true, maxbibnames=199, sortlocale=en_US, style=numeric]{biblatex} % for bibliography management
% \usepackage{booktabs} % for professional-looking tables
\usepackage{color, colortbl} % for color support
\usepackage{csquotes} % for advanced quotation handling
\usepackage{efbox} % for framed boxes
\usepackage{amsmath} % for advanced mathematical typesetting
\usepackage{enumitem} % for customizing lists
\usepackage[shortcuts]{extdash} % for hyphenation of words with dashes
\usepackage[tt=false]{libertine} % for a specific font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % for font encoding
\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc} % for customizing footnotes
\usepackage[showframe=false, pass=true]{geometry} % for page layout customization
\usepackage{graphicx} % for including graphics
\usepackage{pgfplots} % for creating plots
\usepackage{hyphenat} % for hyphenation control
\usepackage{amsfonts} % for mathematical fonts
\usepackage{braket} % for Dirac notation
% \usepackage{parnotes} % for footnotes in tables
\usepackage{pdflscape} % for landscape pages
\usepackage{pifont} % for special symbols
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for advanced text alignment
\usepackage{seqsplit} % for splitting long sequences of characters
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{siunitx} % for typesetting SI units
\usepackage{subcaption} % for subfigures and subtables
% \usepackage{tabularx} % for advanced table formatting
\usepackage{xcolor} % for color support
\usepackage{xspace} % for intelligent spacing
\usepackage{url} % for typesetting URLs
\usepackage{hyperref} % for hyperlinks
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% \usepackage[
%   breaklinks    = true,
%   colorlinks    = true,
%   hypertexnames = True,
%   pdfpagelabels = false,
%   citecolor     = {blue!80!black},
%   linkcolor     = {blue!80!black},
%   urlcolor      = {blue!80!black},
% ]{hyperref} % load hyperref as the last package

% pkg: biblatex
\setlength\bibitemsep{0.5\baselineskip}                 % add a line between entries
\AtEveryBibitem{\iffieldundef{doi}{}{\clearfield{url}}} % if DOI, hide URL

\addbibresource{thesis.bib}

% pkg: siunitx
% some guidelines https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/checklist.html
\sisetup{
  tight-spacing  = true
  ,detect-family = true
  ,detect-mode   = true
  ,binary-units  = true    % support for MB, GB, etc.
  ,range-units   = single  % "3% to 5%" -> "3 to 5%"
  ,range-phrase  = --      % "3 to 5%"  -> "3--5%"
}

% pkg: babel, hyperref
\addto\extrasenglish{%
  \renewcommand{\chapterautorefname}{Chapter}
  \renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{Section}
  \renewcommand{\subsectionautorefname}{Section}
  \renewcommand{\subsubsectionautorefname}{Section}
}

% pkg: url
\renewcommand{\UrlFont}{\footnotesize\tt}

% our custom commands
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmtt} % use computer modern for teletype

%%% draft mode / toggle commands %%%
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{draft}
\settoggle{draft}{true} % change toggle for draft or final versions

\iftoggle{draft}{
  % if 'draft' toggle is true
  \overfullrule=10pt                       % highlight overfull hboxes
}{
  % if 'draft' toggle is false
  \PassOptionsToPackage{final}{showlabels} % hide labels on figures, etc
}

% if you're including existing papers into your thesis, it helps to put
% content behind a toggle (or conditional) so you only have to maintain
% and keep consistency on one copy. see "introduction.tex".
\newtoggle{thesis}
\settoggle{thesis}{true}

% \usepackage[inline]{showlabels} % only used for debugging
% \renewcommand{\showlabelfont}{\sffamily \color{blue}}
% \renewcommand{\showlabelsetlabel}[1]{\efbox{\showlabelfont #1}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%% front matter %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

% title should be all caps
\title{HARNESSING CLASSICAL CONTROL FOR GENERATING ARBITRARY QUANTUM DYNAMICS IN SUPERCONDUCTING QUBITS}
% ALT TITLE: DEVELOPMENT OF NOVEL STOCHASTIC AND HAMILTONIAN CONTROL TECHNIQUES FOR SUPERCONDUCTING QUBITS 

% use your full name!
% https://cs.stanford.edu/~knuth/news19.html
% "Let's celebrate everybody's full names"
\author{Evangelos Vlachos}
 
% major should be all caps
\majorfield{PHYSICS}

% date should be May, August, or December (when degrees are conferred)
\submitdate{August 2024}

%%% preface %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{preface}
  % \prefacesection{Dedication}
  \input{chapters/dedication.tex}

  % \prefacesection{Acknowledgements}
  \input{chapters/acknowledgements.tex}

  {
  \hypersetup{hidelinks} % color all links black in the preface
  \tableofcontents
  \listoftables
  \listoffigures
  }

  % \prefacesection{Abstract}
  \input{chapters/abstract.tex}

\end{preface}

%%% introduction %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% \input{chapters/introduction.tex}

% \input{chapters/light_matter_interaction.tex}

\input{chapters/noise-sources.tex}

\input{chapters/open-quantum-systems.tex}
  
\input{chapters/hardware.tex}

\input{chapters/master-equation-paper.tex}

\input{chapters/coherence-stabilization.tex}


%%% conclusions %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\input{chapters/conclusions.tex}

%%% bibliography %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%  \printbibliography in biblatex is great, but doesn't allow for the
%  greatest customization, so we'll use the package biblatex + biber
%  backend to meet some requirements:
%
%  * bibliography should be an un-numbered chapter, and still have a
%    pdfbookmark and a line in the table of contents
%
%  * bibliography contents should be singlespace, and optionally a smaller
%    font
%
%  * first line of this "chapter" should be in the same spot as the first
%    line of preface sections (e.g., acknowledgement)
%
%  * we use \raggedright so things like URLs and DOIs aren't stretched out.
%
\clearpage
\chapter*{Bibliography}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}

\begin{singlespace}
  % increase penalty such that we don't break entries over pages
  % source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43275
  \patchcmd{\bibsetup}{\interlinepenalty=5000}{\interlinepenalty=10000}{}{}

  % reduce spacing between each bibentry
  \setlength\bibitemsep{0.9\baselineskip}

  % don't justify-align entries: this prevents stretching out each line
  \raggedright
  \printbibliography[heading = none]
\end{singlespace}

\end{document}


well without your unknown class nobody can test. Also it is quite unclear what is  the first error. But the "loaded in a group" error indicates that you have a newer latex on your desktop.

Off-topic: you should sort out your preamble. Don't load stuff you don't need and check the loading order. Don't load inputenc either once or twice.

you have posted far too much code and no one can use any of it as it \input files not provided, please provide a small example that demonstrates the error. The document fragment shown in an image at the start of the question appears unrelated to the error messages shown in the image, but please don't use images for code or error messages, it makes it hard to debug.

I figured out what was wrong. There was a field in one of the bibliographic entries that was wrong. Sigh

Thank you for all the recommendations everyone. I will take those into consideration next time I post a question here.
