# Strange reference behaviour. (References disappearing randomly)

Tags: bibtex, pdftex, hyperref, natbib

I am using the MNRAS class https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mnras?lang=en, and I have a very strange behaviour with my references.

I am using BibTex, and some times the file compiles correctly and some other doesn't. For example. I have a table in the middle of the text (with a cross-reference), and if is use:

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}

\begin{tabular}
\end{table}
```

the code complies correctly and all the reference appear.

If I change to the starred version:

```
\begin{table*}
\begin{tabular}

\begin{tabular}
\end{table*}
```

then, all my references disappear and are replaced with question mark symbols!!!

What can be causing this?

EDITED:

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{tab:a}
\begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
 %HERE GOES THE TABLE
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Edit2:

I noticed that is not the table in particular that causes the issue. If I remove the table or move it, it get the error:

**"pdftex Error \pdfendlink ended up in different nesting level than > \pdfstartlink"**

This is my preamble:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Basic setup. Most papers should leave these options alone.
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,usenatbib]{mnras}

% MNRAS is set in Times font. If you don't have this installed (most LaTeX
% installations will be fine) or prefer the old Computer Modern fonts, comment
% out the following line
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
% Depending on your LaTeX fonts installation, you might get better results with one of these:
%\usepackage{mathptmx}
%\usepackage{txfonts}

% Use vector fonts, so it zooms properly in on-screen viewing software
% Don't change these lines unless you know what you are doing
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ae,aecompl}


%%%%% AUTHORS - PLACE YOUR OWN PACKAGES HERE %%%%%

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{slantsc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{2pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{2pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\Roman{table}}

% Only include extra packages if you really need them. Common packages are:
\usepackage{graphicx}   % Including figure files
\usepackage{amsmath}    % Advanced maths commands
\usepackage{amssymb}    % Extra maths symbols


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%% AUTHORS - PLACE YOUR OWN COMMANDS HERE %%%%%

\newcommand{\noop}[1]{}
```

Comment: Where in the `table` or `table*` environment does the citation command occur? In the caption, or somewhere else? Please augment your code snippets to show an actual citation command.

Comment: For the error "! pdfTeX error (ext4): `\pdfendlink` ended up in different nesting level than `\pdfstartlink`.", see the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/249743/16967), which I have written today.

Comment: Thanks @HeikoOberdiek ! I'm not very technical and latex, but your solution including \null\vfill\newpage and \null\kern.95\textheight seem to work, but the document end up with a missive white space between the text (The figures and tables are forced to be placed beginning in page number 3). It seems to be a problem with the float positioning of the tables and figures. I tried to use \usepackage{float} with \begin{table*}[H], to position the within the text, but it doesn't work, the table is placed at the top of the page and a [H] appears as if it was text. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: @Jemme `\null\vfill\newpage\null\kern.95\textheight` is not a solution. It is part of the MWE to move the link at the page border. If you want to try a solution, then you can start with the latest code block in my answer about replacing `\box` with `\unvbox`. But without a MWE and an unclear problem description, it is only a shot in the dark.