# ! pdfTeX error (ext4): \pdfendlink ended up in different nesting level than \pd

Tags: bibtex, pdftex

I get the error `! pdfTeX error (ext4): \pdfendlink ended up in different nesting level than \pd` when trying to compile. I'm on texlive/texmaker on Linux. It was compiling fine before I added another source in bibtex, now it craps out. I've tried deleting the sources I entered, didn't work. I tried deleting all files apart from the .tex and .bib files I use to compile - still same error.

Comment: This happens sometimes, when a link is broken across pages.

Comment: I've tried removing links, and it worked.
However, the error persists if I add any more sources to my library, link in it or not. If I have just the initial references, it compiles. If I add ANYTHING, this error comes back. It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Related or duplicate(?): [‘\pdfendlink ended up in different nesting level than \pdfstartlink’ error with current version of hyperref](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/249579/16967)