# \pdfendlink ended up in different nesting level than \pd

Tags: bibtex, errors, pdftex, hyperref, texlive

I am facing a rather weird issue. I am writing a paper using the `svjour3` class. At some point I realized that adding one letter gave the following error

```
\pdfendlink ended up in different nesting level than \pd
```

I searched to find a possible solution and I was pointed out to change `TeX`'s capacity. The more weird is that there doesn't seem to be a problem because this how much memory is used

```
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
16095 strings out of 493069
303810 string characters out of 6138222
367944 words of memory out of 5000000
19329 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
11810 words of font info for 47 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
1137 hyphenation exceptions out of 819
```

So I don't think that this is the issue here. Unfortunately I cannot provide a `MWE` so I will give my code .

I am also giving a [link with the files](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o9bt3ijbugg9gxc/TeXse.zip?dl=0) required by the class.

At some point I deleted all the output files and tried to rebuild the tex code and surprisingly it worked! Then I realized that the problem occurs when I ran `BibTeX`. So unless I ran `BibTeX` everything works.

Any idea on what might be the issue?

For reference I am running `TeXLive` under `Feodra 25` using `TeXMaKeR`.

Comment: This usually occurs if a longer, hyperlinked, textual citation is broken between two pages in two-column format with a two-column-spanning float (`figure*` ore `table*`)  on one of the pages. [**This workaround**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/368731) might help you.